# fetching a http process user using bash

Tags: regex, bash, http, process

Whats the best way to fetch a web process user (apache|nginx|www-data) for bash script usage?

In my case for setting up folder permissions and changing to the poper owner.

Currently I'm using:

```
ps aux | grep -E "(www-data|apache|nginx).*(httpd|apache2|nginx)" \
| grep -o "^[a-z\-]*" | head -n1
```

inside a bash script to fetch the owner of the http process.

Any hints on a more smartly solution or a better regex whould be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will really depend on your operating system.  One option might be to check whether likely candidates exist in your password file:

```
user=$(awk -F: '/www|http/{print $1;exit}' /etc/passwd)
```

If you really want to look for the owner of *running* processes, remember that Apache often launches a root-owned "master" process, then launches children as the web user.  So perhaps something like this:

```
user=$(ps aux|awk '$1=="root"{next} /www|http|apache/{print $1;exit}')
```

But you should also be able to determine things based on OS detection, since things tend to follow standards:

```
case "`uname -s`" in
  Darwin)  user=_www; uid=70 ;;
  FreeBSD) user=www; uid=80 ;;
  Linux)
    if grep Ubuntu /etc/lsb-release; then
      user=www-data; uid=$(id -u www-data)
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
      user=www-data; uid=$(id -u www-data)
    elif etc
      etc
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

I'm not up on the best ways to detect different Linux distros, so that may require a bit of additional research for you.